# Spring boot data jpa - how to work with legacy databases which do not have sequences on tables

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, db2

I'm looking for an advice on how to work with the tables which do not have sequences. I'm working with very old DB2 database via spring boot project. For some reason there are no sequences for tables. The sequences in this table are tracked in the separate table, which imitates sequence properties like range and last id used. So when a new record is inserted in some table the corresponding record in id generation table is getting updated with last_used_id increment and so on. Can anyone advice the best way of approaching id generation and use it on POJOs if adding sequence with triggers for existing tables is not an option?

Comment: Does your `very old DB2 database` support the `generate_unique()` function? If not, what's the DB2 version and platform?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the concept of an identity column was crafted manually using a sequence.

You may want to consider modifying the table to explicitly use an identity column for the purpose of automatically generating a unique value when a record is inserted into the table.

Some info you may find useful:
Sequences compared to identity columns: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0007010.html
Determining when to use identity columns or sequences: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0004994.html
Auto numbering and identifier columns: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0020108.html